# Delete rows based on cell value not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in sheet called New, and my data are in column A to column K. However, column E to H are intentionally left blank for data analysis purposes and I have no header so my data starts from cell A1. Now in column A we have color in cell, I would like to delete any rows that aren't white so keep rows that don't have color in it.

I did some research but all of the codes I got online either delete the whole sheet or just pass through codes and nothing happens. Below are the ones I am currently using that doesn't do anything. I use F8 and still no error.

See image for my sample data and I am trying to get the results with cells that don't have any color in it. I tried to remove quotation mark for the color index but still it doesn't work.

```
 Sub deleterow()

 lastRow = Worksheets("New").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
      If Worksheets("New").Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex <> "2" Then
           Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
           i = i + 1
      End If
 Next I

 End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub deleterow()

Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long

With Worksheets("New")
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
        'If .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color <> xlNone Then
        ' replace RGB(255, 255, 255) with the "white" color
        If .Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color <> RGB(255, 255, 255) Then
            .Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but your codes deletes the whole sheet.

Comment: @sc1324 is your color in column A white ? or empty ?

Comment: There are no blank cells in any of the columns except column E to column H. In column A some cells have color some don't so I am trying to remove rows if there is a cell color in column A.

Comment: @sc1324 not empty as values, and color. try edited code.

Comment: I mean the blank cells in column A will mean if we reach the end of the data range and that is why we have `lastrow` defined.

Comment: Sweet thank you, I have been trying to get this to work since last night. Greatly appreciated for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

## Delete No Color Row

### Union Version

```
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteNoColorRow()

    Const cSheet As Variant = "Sheet1"  ' Worksheet Name/Index
    Const cFirstR As Integer = 1        ' First Row
    Const cColumn As Variant = "A"      ' Column Letter/Number

    Dim rngU As Range     ' Union Range
    Dim lastRow As Long   ' Last Row
    Dim i As Long         ' Row Counter

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSheet)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, cColumn).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = cFirstR To lastRow
            If .Cells(i, cColumn).Interior.ColorIndex <> xlNone Then
                If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngU = Union(rngU, .Cells(i, cColumn))
                  Else
                    Set rngU = .Cells(i, cColumn)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With

    If Not rngU Is Nothing Then
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete ' Hidden = True
        Set rngU = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```